# Get Unique Process ID MSTest Parallel Testing

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, mstest

I used to work with Nunit3 where my tests would run a new thread. I was able to get a unique and consistent ID based on the ThreadID they were using. Now that I have moved over to MSTest V2, in Assembly Parallel testing is not using unique threads per worker.

I need a method in which each worker has their own ID. Is there a way to achieve this?

I Should mention that the value must be obtainable inside of a static field/method or property. So something like Process.Id as far as i know, will not work.

Comment: Why do you need to get the ID? What are you doing with it? I've used both NUnit and MSTest and run tests in parallel and never needed it so I'm curious how you are using it.

Comment: The way I set up my framework, sets my Selenium Scripts to be independent to my test cases. The test cases request an action to the static selenium script. This script then finds the node its working with based on an ID. Then performs the action with the web driver the node has. 

I set it up this way to handle multiple threads, but im open to other suggestions

Comment: It sounds like you are doing a lot of heavy lifting on your own. NUnit is built to allow scripts to run in parallel, you just have to write them as independent tests and let NUnit take over. It will handle driver management for you. Take a look at the NUnit documentation and some NUnit examples.

Comment: I will revise my solution and try to take into account the features that are available to me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId property.

Comment: please provide some sample code to show how it should be used, your answer is currently unclear

Comment: Actually I was wrong. The only way I found is to track not thread ID but test case name.